# Java Read text file into a stream and split it

Tags: java, file, split, java-8, java-stream

I want to read a text file with a stream and save it into an array.

lets say my text file looks like this

`; Kommentar
G40 K88 F32
H38
; noch ein Kommentar
B55
H33 K34 Bla77`

now I want an array or an arraylist thats look like this

```
G40
K88
F32
H38
B55
H33
K34
Bla77
```

So I want to delete lines that starts with a ";" and split every thing else after a space.

I tryid it like this:

```
 List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {


        list = stream
                .filter(line -> !line.startsWith(";"))
        //  .map(string -> list.split(" "))
                .map(String::toUpperCase)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

print:

```
G40 K88 F32
H38
B55
H33 K34 BLA77
```

With the function .map(string -> list.split(" ")) I'll get this error `The method split(String) is undefined for the type List<String>`

I am new to Java and after hours of searching, I couldn't find an answer. Hope someone here can give me a hint. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To split line and create stream containing its elements use

```
line -> Stream.of(line.split("\\s+"))
//OR 
//line -> Arrays.stream(line.split("\\s+"))
```

This lambda creates `Stream<String>` but if we use it with `map` like

```
map(line -> Stream.of(line.split("\\s+")))
```

we will get `Stream<Stream<String>>`. This is not what we want because we don't want to "iterate" over streams, but over its elements. So we want to "flatten" this structure to get `Stream<String>`.

This can be achieved with

```
flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split("\\s+")))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
list = stream
     .filter(line -> !line.startsWith(";"))           // filters out comments
     .map(String::toUpperCase)                        // uppercase
     .flatMap(string -> Stream.of(string.split(" "))) // flattens the split array to the 
                                                      // Stream elements and adds to the 
                                                      // current Stream
     .collect(Collectors.toList());                   // as List
```

[`Stream::flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element (from the documentation).

Very nice examples are on the [Baeldung's webpage](http://www.baeldung.com/java-difference-map-and-flatmap).

Answer (score 1):

For an all in one line solution try:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("your/file/path"))
     .filter(l -> !l.startsWith(";"))
     .flatMap(l -> Arrays.stream(l.split("\n")))
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```